# List Google Drive files metadata

Tags: list, google-drive-api

```
 drive.files.list(
  {
    // pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, parents)"
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
    listToShow = res.data
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      console.log("Files:");
      files.map((file) => {            
        console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No files found.");
    }
  }
);
```

Here is excerpt of result looks like:

```
"files": [
    {
      "id": "1v922pMgws8pzuIsdJd8ziAJdTXJq237A",
      "name": "January",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
      "parents": [
        "1mjmkzpFUo_nsjgzOnA4lfi_b8bfJR2mP"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "1_JLPz8CBvNJmNmyjvv70W5oRkuTAs0a4",
      "name": "Bills",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
      "parents": [
        "1EjaQDd4lmDZvdjAVMrDr2hZ78vBSuEFU"
      ]
    }
]
```

I am using this for metadata my reference
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

I am trying to get more fields displayed in my result like sharingUser, owners[]

I am modifying the line 4 of code as below :

```
fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, parents , sharingUser, owners[])"
```

Error Log :Error: Invalid field selection nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, parents , sharingUser, owners[] )

What is the syntax to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your field value is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, parents , sharingUser, owners[])"
```

#### To:

```
fields: "nextPageToken,files(id,name,mimeType,parents,sharingUser,owners)"
```

#### Other case:

When you want to retrieve all fields, you can use the following fields.

```
fields: "nextPageToken,files,kind,incompleteSearch"
```

and

```
fields: "*"
```

#### Note:

- In this case, `*` can be used for the method of Files: list of Drive API v3. But for example, at the get method in Sheets API, all fields cannot be retrieved by `*`. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)